# How to write DRY code when setting variable names from string literals?

Tags: python

In short, is there a pythonic way to write `SETTING_A = os.environ['SETTING_A']`?

I want to provide a module `environment.py` from which I can import constants that are read from environment variables.

###### Approach 1:

```
import os

try:
    SETTING_A = os.environ['SETTING_A']
    SETTING_B = os.environ['SETTING_B']
    SETTING_C = os.environ['SETTING_C']
except KeyError as e:
    raise EnvironmentError(f'env var {e} is not defined')
```

###### Approach 2

```
import os

vs = ('SETTING_A', 'SETTING_B', 'SETTING_C')

try:
    for v in vs:
        locals()[v] = os.environ[v]
except KeyError as e:
    raise EnvironmentError(f'env var {e} is not defined')
```

Approach 1 repeats the names of the variables, approach 2 manipulates `locals` and it's harder to see what constants will be importable from the module.

Is there a best practice to this problem?

Comment: Why are you defining these settings as individual variables? These are already encapsulated in a dictionary which saves you all the repetitive code. Furthermore, [`python-decouple`](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) might be worth having a look at.

Comment: @albert writing `os.environ['SETTING_A']` over and over again in different places seems more repetitive to me. Other than that I just think it's nice to have constants as variables. The user of the library shouldn't even be aware where they come from. And finally, an uppercase variable implies that it's supposed to be a constant, while the value of `os.environ[something]` may change during runtime.

Comment: You can give it another, shorter name, like `env = os.environ`, or directly `import os.environ as env`. Keeping your environment variables in a common dict can have many advantages over having some independant global variables.

Comment: Whatever you do, do **not** work with *locals()* unless you're absolutely certain of the implications. You can reasonably assume that the class returned by *os.environ* has an efficient implementation of \_\_getitem__ so calling it repetitively is unlikely to be expensive. If in doubt, build your own dictionary

Comment: I would usually go with [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) for setting environment variables. It's easy to use and does what you are seeking to do without any complications.

Answer (score 1):

Use [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) to set environment variables.

```
pip install python-decouple
```

Now you can create a .ini or .env file and store your variables there.

```py
.env

SETTING_A=os.environ['SETTING_A'] 
SETTING_B=os.environ['SETTING_B']
SETTING_C=os.environ['SETTING_C']
```

Now in your settings file you can import the env variables and use them.

```py
from decouple import config

setting_a = config('SETTING_A')
setting_b = config('SETTING_B')
setting_c = config('SETTING_C')
```

Note that while setting your env variables you shouldn't leave gap with `"="` and you should use `config('')` to load them.

Comment: Thank you. It does not seem possible to prevent duplicated typing of `SETTING_X` .

Comment: if you put the settings in a list then you can index the item you want and not repeat the same code over and over. `settings=[SETTING_A, SETTING_B, SETTING_C,...]` and you can use `settings[0], settings[1], settings[2],...` to get which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pydantic to achieve this

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class _Settings(BaseSettings):
    SETTING_A: str
    SETTING_B: str
    SETTING_C: str

class SettingsHandler:
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):

        root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        _file_path = f"{root_dir}/local.env"

        if os.path.exists(ini_file_path):
            return _Settings(_env_file=ini_file_path, _env_file_encoding="utf-8")

        return _Settings()

SETTINGS = SettingsHandler.generate()
```

Now you can use this SETTINGS object. Sample usage is written below

```
print(SETTINGS.SETTING_A)
print(SETTINGS.SETTING_B)
print(SETTINGS.SETTING_C)
```

Sample env file

```
SETTING_A="value_of_setting_a"
SETTING_B="value_of_setting_b"
SETTING_C="value_of_setting_c"
```

Comment: Thank you. How's the local.env file supposed to look like?

Comment: Updated my answer with sample loca.env